# VB .NET simple server example doesn't show received data in a list box

Tags: vb.net, server, tcplistener

I am writing a simple TCP server. I can connect and send messages to it but I think I have some issue with threads and invokes because I don't manage to add the received message to a listbox, although the message is shown in a msgbox correctly.

The code compile and run without any complains, so I have no clue about what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone help me? what is wrong in this code?

This is the main class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO


Public Class MC_main

    Dim Listener As New TcpListener(61100)
    Dim Client As New TcpClient
    Dim server_connections_cnt As Integer
    Dim do_exit As Boolean

    Private Sub MC_main_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        'MsgBox("Form closed")
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub MC_main_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'MsgBox("Form closing")
        do_exit = True
    End Sub


    Private Sub MC_main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        do_exit = False
        ' Create listener thread
        Dim ListenerThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        ListenerThread.Start()

    End Sub

    ' LISTENER THREAD
    Private Sub Listening()

        Dim clientSocket As TcpClient = Nothing

        Listener.Start()

        lstDebug_addItem("Server Started")  ' THIS IS ADDED TO THE LSTBOX
        server_connections_cnt = 0
        While (do_exit = False)
            clientSocket = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()
            server_connections_cnt += 1

            lstDebug_addItem("Client " + Convert.ToString(server_connections_cnt) + " started!")  ' THIS IS ADDED TO THE LSTBOX
            Dim wsCon As New handleWSconnection
            wsCon.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(server_connections_cnt))
        End While

        If Not IsNothing(clientSocket) Then
            clientSocket.Close()
        End If

        Listener.Stop()
    End Sub

    Public Sub lstDebug_addItem(msg As String)

        If lstDebug.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New lstBox_addItem_Delegate(AddressOf AddItemLstBox), Me.lstDebug, msg)
        Else
            ' ENTER HERE WHEN CALLED FROM THE OTHER CLASS
            MsgBox(msg)  ' THIS MESSAGEBOX SHOWS THE MESSAGE
            lstDebug.Items.Add("Message: " + msg)  ' THIS ITEM IS NOT ADDED TO THE lstDebug LISTBOX, WHY?
        End If
    End Sub


    Public Delegate Sub lstBox_addItem_Delegate(ByRef lstbox As ListBox, ByVal str As String)
    Public Sub AddItemLstBox(ByRef lstbox As ListBox, ByVal str As String)
        lstbox.Items.Add(str)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the class where I handle new clients:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class handleWSconnection

    Dim WSocket As TcpClient
    Dim clNo As String

    Public Sub startClient(ByVal inWSocket As TcpClient, ByVal clineNo As String)
        Me.WSocket = inWSocket
        Me.clNo = clineNo
        Dim wsCon As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf wsConnection))
        wsCon.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub wsConnection()
        Dim bytesFrom(1024) As Byte
        Dim dataFromClient As String
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
        Dim serverResponse As String
        Dim rCount As String
        Dim alive As Boolean

        alive = True

        While (alive)
            Try
                Dim myNetworkStream As NetworkStream = WSocket.GetStream()

                If myNetworkStream.CanRead Then
                    Dim myReadBuffer(1024) As Byte
                    Dim numberOfBytesRead As Integer = 0

                    ' Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
                    Do
                        numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length)
                        dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer)
                        MC_main.lstDebug_addItem(dataFromClient) 'THIS IS THE CALL THAT DOES NOTHING.. I WANT TO ADD THE RECEIVED STRING TO THE LISTBOX
                    Loop While myNetworkStream.DataAvailable
                Else
                    MsgBox("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Exception: " + ex.ToString)
                alive = False
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thnks!

Comment: For the one that down voted my question without giving a reason: thank you for your input, it has been very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN page on the ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx#Anchor_3), try this:

```
// Shutdown the painting of the ListBox as items are added.
lstDebug.BeginUpdate();

lstDebug.Items.Add("Message: " + msg);

// Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
lstDebug.EndUpdate();
```